# Spotipy - Cannot log in to authenticate (Authorization Code Flow)

Tags: python-3.x, spotify, spotipy

I am working with the Spotipy Python library to connect to the Spotify web API. I want to get access to my Spotify's user account via [Authorization Code Flow](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#authorization-code-flow). I am using Python 3.5, Spotipy 2.4.4, Google Chrome 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit) and Mac OS Sierra 10.12.2

First, I went to [the Spotify Developer website](https://developer.spotify.com/my-applications) to register the program to get a Client ID, a Client Secret key and enter a redirect URI (https://www.google.com) on my white-list.

Second, I set the environment variables from terminal:

```
export SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID='my_spotify_client_id'
export SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET='my_spotify_client_secret'
export SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI='https://www.google.com'
```

Then I try to run the example code typing 'python3.5 script.py my_username' from terminal. Here is the script:

```
import sys
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util

scope = 'user-library-read'

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    username = sys.argv[1]
else:
    print "Usage: %s username" % (sys.argv[0],)
    sys.exit()

token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope)

if token:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
    results = sp.current_user_saved_tracks()
    for item in results['items']:
        track = item['track']
        print track['name'] + ' - ' + track['artists'][0]['name']
else:
    print "Can't get token for", username
```

When running this code, it takes me to a log in screen on my browser. I enter my Spotify's credential to grant access to my app. But when I finally click on 'log in' (or 'Iniciar sesión' in Spanish) nothing happens. I tried to log in with my Facebook account but it does not work either. It seems that I get a Bad Request every time that I click on 'log in'. Here is a capture of Chrome:

[image]

The process is incomplete because when trying to enter the redirect URI back on terminal I get another Bad Request:

```
raise SpotifyOauthError(response.reason)
spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOauthError: Bad Request
```

I tried to restart my computer, clean my browser cookies, use another different browser but did not work. It seems that [I am not the only one](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/issues/105) having [this problem](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/issues/80). Is it maybe a bug? Please, avoid answers like "read the documentation of the API going [here](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/)". Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. In order to run the [Authorization Code Flow example code](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#authorization-code-flow) provided in the Spotipy's documentation correctly, I specified the redirect URI in line 13 of the example script when calling util.prompt_for_user_token, even when I had done this previously when setting environment variables:

```
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, redirect_uri = 'https://example.com/callback/')
```

Likewise, do not use https://www.google.com or similar web address as your redirect URI. Instead, try 'https://example.com/callback/' or 'http://localhost/' as suggested [here](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#authorized-requests). Do not forget that the redirected URL once you are logged in must have the word code included.

Cheers,